# JavaScript: Regex on decimals formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

In my current app, I am implementing field validation with regex for forms.

More specifically, I am having trouble handling edge-case for numbers with decimals.

Essentially I am using regex to prevent users from typing wrong information in to the input fields.

For instance, if user would type `12.2` and then `.` afterwards, I am using regex to detect what shouldn't be there, and replace with empty string, `''`

Here's my current implementation using a call back function:

```
export const checkFormat = (typeFormat, value) => {
  //value is stringified
  switch (typeFormat) {
    //...
    case NUMERIC_DECIMALS: {
      return value.replace(/(\d+\.\d+)(\.*)\d*/g, '$1')
    }
  }

}
```

However, the current regex implementation can't handle such cases as

- User types : `.`, then `..` ==> `.`
- User types : `123.2`, then `1.23.2` ==> `1.232`

I'm fairly new to Regex, so obviously it needs some work

Comment: just don't replace on the fly, it is annoing

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Could you please elaborate some more on the input and expected output?

Comment: Could you give the list of valid and invalid inputs and expected output?

Comment: for these three input: a) 1.2  b)1.23  c)1.2.3.4 the output should be : a)1.2
b)1.23
c) 1.2 is that correct ?

Comment: if you only want decimal, why not replace every non-digit char after first dot? so, `1.00sdsdsd = 1.00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)).*$
```

and replace by this:

```
$1
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/KW2KOr/1/)

Or to get the a more complex solution, which I guess you are looking for, you may try this:

```js
const regex = /^(\d+(?:\.\d*))|(\.)?/gm;
const str = ["1.2","...","g..g","1.23","1.2.3.4",".,",".,","123.2","1.23.2","14","1","15.6.4789756465","g"];
const replaceRegex = /[^\.\d]/gm;
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
var res=str[i].replace(replaceRegex,'').split(regex);
var finalResult="";
var alreadyContainsDot=false;
for(var j=0;j<res.length;j++)
  if(res[j]!=null && res[j]!="")
  {
    if(res[j].includes(".") && !alreadyContainsDot)
      alreadyContainsDot=true;
    else if(res[j].includes(".") && alreadyContainsDot)
      res[j]=res[j].replace(/\./gm,'');
    finalResult+=res[j];
  }
console.log(str[i]+"==>"+finalResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If my interpretation of the requirement is correct, this should work:

```
const regex = /(\d+\.?\d+?)(\D+)/g;
const str = `131/1.13.ad`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/HWAft4/1)

Answer (score 0):

It is bad UX practice to monitor what the user is typing and change his input out from underneath him. He is likely to think his keyboard is broken. I don't know when or how this approach became so widespread, but thankfully it seems to be dying out.

In any case, it is always a bad idea to try to do things with numbers using regexps, which are fundamentally designed for manipulating strings. If for some reason you need to check if some string is a valid number, use numeric APIs such as `!isNaN(+value)`.

Use the appropriate `type` or `pattern` attributes on your input fields to do validation. If that does not suffice, validate when the user presses the "Submit" button or equivalent.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However, my client insistently wants this feature, which I've opposed from the beginning but they've decided to have it anyway :/